# How to download file from a batch file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

I have some files that contain  **one URL per line**, like

- https://url/url/url.com/page-1.jpg
- https://url/url/url.com/a.mp3
- https://url/url/url.com/b.mp3

....

I try to code for:

```
import wget

with open ("5074_url.txt", encoding='utf-8', mode = 'r') as f:
    for line in list(f): # OR f.readlines()
        filename = wget.download(line)
        print (filename)
```

but raise Error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Geturl2.py\", line 33, in <module>
    filename = wget.download(line)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 506, in download
    (fd, tmpfile) = tempfile.mkstemp(".tmp", prefix=prefix, dir=".")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tempfile.py", line 342, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tempfile.py", line 260, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '.\\page-1.jpg\ngjf6wrvy.tmp'
```

**\ngjf6wrvy.tmp**  What's this ? There's no this in file, I'm sure that.

I'm using Python 3.6.5 on windows 10

I know it could use `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)` , 
but it has filename option. I don't wanna change filename. 
So How don't change filename ?

**[Solved]**

```
import wget

with open ("5074_url.txt", encoding='utf-8', mode = 'r') as f:
    for url in f.readlines():
        filename = wget.download(url.strip())
        print (filename)
```

**Thank you so much for help !!!**

Comment: you might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Comment: @usr2564301 Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10

Comment: If you're only looking to download files, then I don't get it why @candah's link is useless? It does exactly what you're looking for or did I get something wrong?

Comment: I try use "r = urllib.request.urlopen(url.strip())" , and "urlretrieve" . it does not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve exactly, but here's an example with requests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

import requests


with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for url in f.readlines():
        r = requests.get(url.strip())
        print(r)
```

This will "download" each URL contained in `test.txt` and store in memory. The variable `r` contains the [Response object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

Comment: No any file to be downloaded.<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>

Comment: It will download it an keep it in "memory" until you store it. So you need another `open()` of a new file and store the content in there. Or you go with the link proposed by @candah: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Comment: I try use "r = urllib.request.urlopen(url.strip())" , and "urlretrieve" . it does not works.

Comment: urllib.request.urlretrieve have contains filename option. I don't wanna change filename. So How ?

Comment: Thank you for your code about "url.strip()". it works fine when use wget .